# Get text snippets from google results

Tags: java, html, json, google-search

I want to extract the snippets from the google results, I'm using the following code that parse the google results page:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the search term.");
    String searchTerm = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of results. Example: 5 10 20");
    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();

    String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q="+searchTerm+"&num="+num;

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();

    Elements results = doc.select("//div//div//span[contains(@class, 'st')]/text()");

    for (Element result : results) {
        String linkText = result.text();
        System.out.println("Text::" + linkText );//1000+ ", URL::" + linkHref.substring(6, linkHref.indexOf("&")));
    }
```

it extract the resulted url and the caption, the problem is that the snippets are in html tags that are in "lower level", like in the attached image:

[image]

So how can i extract them ?!

Comment: If this is java or groovy, add this tag (add your language name in tags)

Comment: @Gilles .. done

Comment: Can you run [tag:xpath] querys ?

Comment: @Gilles, i didn't try .. could it be useful?

Comment: For sure it will be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

With a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query :

```
'//em[.="Stack Overflow"]/following-sibling::text()'
```

or

```
'//em[text()="Stack Overflow"]/following-sibling::text()'
```